# PLS-00103 : Encountered the symbol "~" when expecting one of the following error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using `REF CURSOR` to fetch the data and process it.

```
TYPE ty_ref_cur IS REF CURSOR RETURN MyTable%ROWTYPE;
l_cursor ty_ref_cur;

IF SomeCondition = 'Y' THEN
 OPEN l_cursor for 'SELECT column1, column2
  FROM SomeTable
  WHERE column1 = regexp_replace(SomeColumn, '~', NULL)';
```

When above code is compiled, I am getting   `PLS-00103` : Encountered the symbol "~" when expecting one of the following.. error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of quotes

```
 OPEN l_cursor for SELECT column1, column2
  FROM SomeTable
  WHERE column1 = regexp_replace(SomeColumn, '~', NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not use `single quotations` inside `single quotations`, 
use with `double quotations` instead like this : `regexp_replace(SomeColumn, ''~'', NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
OPEN l_cursor for 'SELECT column1, column2
  FROM SomeTable
  WHERE column1 = regexp_replace(SomeColumn, ''~'', NULL)';
```